# My Bar Plot is not showing bars for all the data values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that contains two features namely `LotFrontage` and `LotArea`.
I want to plot a bar graph to show the relation between them. 
My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
visual_df=pd.DataFrame()
visual_df['area']=df_encoded['LotArea']
visual_df['frontage']=df_encoded['LotFrontage']
visual_df.dropna(inplace=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.bar(visual_df['area'],visual_df['frontage'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Resultant Plot]
The column `LotFrontage` is in Float datatype.
What is wrong with my code and How can I correct it?

[image: visual_df sample]

Comment: Can you show a sample of your `visual_df`?

Comment: Here is the sample, I have added it in the question

Comment: Trying `plt.scatter(visual_df['area'],visual_df['frontage'])` probably will be more informative. PS: please post data as text, never as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see a relationship between two features, a scatter plot is usually much more informative than a bar plot. To draw a scatter plot via matplotlib: `plt.scatter(visual_df['area'], visual_df['frontage'])`. You can also invoke pandas scatter plot, which automatically adds axis labels: `df.plot(kind='scatter', x='area', y='frontage')`.

For a lot of statistical purposes, seaborn can be handy. [`sns.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) not only creates the scatter plot but automatically also tries to fit the data with a linear regression and shows a confidence interval.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

area = [8450, 9600, 11250, 9550, 14260, 14115, 10084, 6120, 7420, 11200, 11924, 10652, 6120, 10791, 13695, 7560, 14215, 7449, 9742, 4224, 14230, 7200]
frontage = [65, 80, 68, 60, 84, 85, 75, 51, 50, 70, 85, 91, 51, 72, 68, 70, 101, 57, 75, 44, 110, 60]
df = pd.DataFrame({'area': area, 'frontage': frontage})

sns.regplot(x='area', y='frontage', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image: example regplot]

PS: The main problem with the intented bar plot is that the x-values lie very far apart. Moreover, the default width is one and very narrow bars can get too narrow to see in the plot. Adding an explicit edge color can make them visible:

```
plt.bar(visual_df['area'], visual_df['frontage'], ec='blue')
```

[image: bar plot]

You could set a larger width, but then some bars would start to overlap.

Alternatively, pandas barplot would treat the x-axis as categorical, showing all x-values next to each other, as if they were strings. The bars are drawn in the order of the dataframe, so you might want to sort first:

```py
df.sort_values('area').plot(kind='bar', x='area', y='frontage')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: pandas bar plot]

Comment: The `seaborn` method is working fine but `df.plot` is not. A lot of different colored bars are coming up when I try to use it. Why is it happening?

Comment: Maybe you don't have a recent pandas version? If you edit your post with a reproducible example someone can have a look to see what 's happening.

Comment: I updated the code of the pandas bar plot with sorting the x-axis. Default you'd get the same order as the dataframe, which is quite confusing. (`print(pd.__version__)` outputs '1.0.3' for the current pandas version)